# Specify a bean to bind data to

Tags: grails

Working in grails allows you to be quite DRY, but I still find myself frequently doing this:

```
def bookInstance = new Book(params)
if (!bookInstance.validate()) {
     render(view: "create", model: [bookInstance: bookInstance])
}
else {
    // stuff...
}
```

Is there a way to specify that a particular controller/action should bind a particular domain and then all the validation and view re-rendering happens before my action is executed? That way I only need to worry about `//stuff...`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Interceptors for validation, but interceptors cant render view.